# Implementing Java Tree Methods

Tags: java

I have to implement recursive methods for a binary tree and wanted to see if the methods I wrote are correctly implemented, as I cannot test them. These are not actual methods. I just need to write the pseudocode of the algorithm.

a) Count number of nodes in a Tree

```
countNodes(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    else{
        TreeNode left = root.getLeftChild();
        TreeNode right = root.getRightChild();
        return (countNodes(left)+countNodes(right)) + 1;
    }
}
```

b) Compute the height of a tree

```
height(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    else{
        return Math.max(height(root.getLeftChild()), height(root.getRightChild()) +1;
    }
}
```

c) Find the maximum element

```
maxElem(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    else{
        int temp = 0;
        temp = Math.max(maxElem(root.getLeftChild()), maxElem(root.getRightChild()));
        return Math.max(root.getValue, temp);
    }
}
```

d) Find the sum of the elements

```
sum(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    else{
        return (sum(root.getLeftChild()) + sum(root.getRightChild())) + root.getValue();
    }
}
```

e) Find the average of the Elements

```
average(TreeNode root){
    int sum = sum(root);
    int elems = countNodes(root);
    return sum/elems;
}
```

f) Find a Specific Item

```
search(int i, TreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
        return false;
    else if(root.getValue == i)
        return true;
    else{ 
        search(i, root.getLeftChild);
        search(i, root.getRightChild);
    }
}
```

g) Determine whether an item is an ancestor of another

```
isAncestor(TreeNode p, NodeNode c){
    if(p==null)
        return false;
    else
        return (c in p.getLeftChild() || c in p.getRightChild())
}
```

h) Determine the highest level that is full

```
maxFull(TreeNode root)
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    else{
        return(numNodes in level h == 2^h - 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? If not, your question might better be answered on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: From this pseudocode, it shouldn't be too hard to create real code. Much of this pseudocode will work as-is or with little modifications. Then you could use a unit test or compare to a standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several minor issues:

1) asMTilsted suggests, if your tree only contains negative values, maxElem does not work
2) The average might not be correct as this is an int and not a double, try type-casting on the sum and count of the tree elements and then return their quotient.
3) in your function search you do not return anything in the last else statement. Try: `return search(i, root.getLeftChild()) || search(i, root.getRightChild());` (also in the rest of your code these are FUNCTIONS and not attributes...

for the rest it seems fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Your MaxElm method is wrong. It will not work if all elements have negative value.

Comment: The elements are supposed to be positive integers. Except that u think the code above is implemented correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to implement recursive methods for a binary tree and wanted to see if the methods I wrote are correctly implemented, as I cannot test them. These are not actual methods. I just need to write the pseudocode of the algorithm.

You **can** test them.

Write them as real code in (say) Java, write some unit tests, run them.

If the stuff you have to submit at the end of the day is pseudo-code not real code, then you can manually translate the Java back into pseudo code ...

---

Strictly speaking, you cannot say whether pseudo-code is correct unless you have specified what the pseudo-code language is / means.